# Value of an array not getting updated

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have this code:

```
import arrays

def range_array(start, stop, step=1):

    if stop == None:
        stop = start
        start = 0

    a_range = range(start, stop, step)
    length = len(a_range)
    an_array = arrays.Array(length)

    for index in range(length): #MISTAKE SOMEWHERE IN THIS LOOP (?)
        an_array[index] == index

    return an_array


def main():
    array = range_array(0, 5)
    print(array)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code starts with a range with values specified in the parameters. Then an array of length a_range is created. This is an empty array, so all of the values equal None. What I want is to make each of the values equal to the index they're in.

This would mean that:

```
an_array[0] = 0
an_array[1] = 1
an_array[n] = n
```

up until the last value of the array. The issue has to be somewhere in the loop

```
for index in range(length): #MISTAKE SOMEWHERE IN THIS LOOP (?)
    an_array[index] == index
```

but I can't seem to find where, the loop iterates correctly, the index goes up from 0 to length correctly, but when I return an_array and print it from main() all values equal to None:

```
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

I'd be very grateful if you could help me out. I have a couple of other functions that depend on this function working properly since they need the array. Thanks.

Comment: `an_array[index] == index` is a comparison, not an assignment.

Comment: Use a simple list comprehension e.g. `return [i for i in range(5)]` or simply `list(range(5))`

Comment: @PeterWood I LOVE YOU

Comment: @HaimarR the feeling is mutual